# Error con assertThrows en junit, Cuando sabes que va a saltar una excepción

Tags: java, eclipse, excepciones, junit

Estoy intentando crear un test sobre un método propio que sirve para desapilar elementos de un vector, He aquí el código que he intentado hasta ahora:

```
@Test
public void testDesapilarStackSinElementos() throws Exception {
    ErrorStackVacio e = new ErrorStackVacio();

    e = assertThrows(ErrorStackVacio.class, () -> **texto en negrita**{stackSinElementos.desapilar().getClass();});

}
```

En teoría debe saltar la excepción y por lo tanto pasar el test, sin embargo, aunque me salte el error al intentar ejecutar el método me sale que el test ha fallado:

[image: fallo del test]

[image: el error se muestra por consola]

Es posible que sea alguna tontería, pero no veo el error. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución, cambiando el tipo de excepción esperado por uno más genérico, no se exactamente porque no me funcionaba antes, incluso poniendo la linea

```
    assertThrows(ErrorStackVacio.class, () -> {stackSinElementos.desapilar().getClass();});
```

no funcionaba. Más abajo podeis ver el codigo que si me funciona:

```
@Test
public void testDesapilarStackSinElementos() throws Exception {

    assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {stackSinElementos.desapilar().getClass();});

}
```